# Save the Logged in User to the database model on form submission with django 1.8

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a model and I am trying to save the user to the models database when the user submits the form. I had a site that did this but now my editor says  *"Use of super on an old style class"*

I am using django 1.8 and i get

> IntegrityError at /auction/createview/ NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   auction_auction.user_id

which is the nicest error I have been able to get. with all the tinkering i have done

```
 class AuctionCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Auction
    action = "created"
    form_class = AuctionForm

    auction_form = AuctionForm(initial={'user':request.user})

class AuctionForm(forms.ModelForm):


class Meta:
    model = Auction
    fields = (
                "user",
                "item_name",
                "reserve",
                "start_date",
                "end_date",

                "description",
                "tags",
        )



 class Auction(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        item_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
        item_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
        winner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='Auction_Winner', blank=True, null=True)
        reserve = MoneyField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')
        created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, null=True)

        slug = AutoSlugField(('slug'), max_length=128, unique=True, populate_from=('item_name',))
        start_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Start date")
        end_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="End date")
        active = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Active')
        total_bids = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Total bids')
        date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Date added')
        last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Last modified')

        description = models.TextField(max_length=3000)


        tags = tagging.fields.TagField()


    #    bid_set = models.IntegerField(default= 0, verbose_name = "Bid set")
        starting_amount = MoneyField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')

        def __unicode__(self):
            return '%s selling %s' % (self.user, self.item_name)

        def _get_increment(self):
            """ add some logic to base incrementing amount on starting price """

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('auction_detail',
                           kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

when i saw [this post](http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2014/05/19/context.html) I thought i'd be able to figure it out. thanks  ★ ✩

Comment: Does the `Auction` model have an `user` field?

Comment: yes, i'll upload the model

Answer (score 0):

You need insert user_id before form save.

AuctionForm - need update request.user value. Added this fields from form initial.

Comment:  can you please give me some example code to help me out - I'd really apreciate it! ⎋ ☯

Comment: `if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AuctionForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)


class AuctionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, user=None, **kwargs):
        self._user = user
        super().__init__(**kwargs)`

After this change self._user this you request.user

Comment: Or added initial. This so nice idea.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to include 'user' on the fields of the Auction form class to solve that error and just put an initial parameter on the form instance in the views.py like

```
auction_form = AuctionForm(initial={'user':request.user})
```

because request.user on the form_valid method will not work at all

Comment:   if i do that i get a drop-down box of users.  Yeah it solves the error but it does I do not want the user needing to find there user account in a drop down list   

Comment: Have you already done my latest comment?? You can just hide the select dropdown list of users in the html through css if you are irritated by it

Comment: I'm working on it, with that i get a AttributeError at /
'module' object has no attribute 'user'   the above post was a reply to your original comment - I'm trying to search what i need to import or whatnot   ++ But it looks like progress

Comment: You get that attribute user error because you did not include user in the fields meta class

Comment: I put it in there and I'm still getting the attribute error

Comment: That's weird, that error occurs when the 'user request'  is not included request.POST because clean dat will search through it, maybe you can edit the codes on your post so I can get a clearer look

Comment: Ok -- Thanks a lot for your help,

Comment: user = Action.objects.get(user=request.user),
auction_form = AuctionForm(initial={'user':user})

This should do the trick